# Solve the Heat Equation with non-zero Dirichlet BCs with Implicit Euler and Conjugate Gradient Linear Solvers?

Tags: julia, differential-equations, differentialequations.jl

Many users have asked how to solve the Heat Equation, u_t = u_xx, with non-zero Dirichlet BCs and with conjugate gradients for the internal linear solver. This is a common simplified PDE problem before moving to more difficult versions of parabolic PDEs. How is this done in DifferentialEquations.jl?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's solve this problem in steps. First, let's build the linear operator for the discretized Heat Equation with Dirichlet BCs. A discussion of the discretization [can be found on this Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTCS_scheme) which shows that the central difference method gives a 2nd order discretization of the second derivative by `(u[i-1] - 2u[i] + u[i+1])/dx^2`. This is the same as multiplying by the Tridiagonal matrix of `[1 -2 1]*(1/dx^2)`, so let's start by building this matrix:

```
using LinearAlgebra, OrdinaryDiffEq
x = collect(-π : 2π/511 : π)

## Dirichlet 0 BCs

u0 = @. -(x).^2 + π^2

n = length(x)
A = 1/(2π/511)^2 * Tridiagonal(ones(n-1),-2ones(n),ones(n-1))
```

Notice that we have implicitly simplified the end, since `(u[0] - 2u[1] + u[2])/dx^2 = (- 2u[1] + u[2])/dx^2` when the left BC is zero, so the term is dropped from the matmul. We then use this discretization of the derivative to solve the Heat Equation:

```
function f(du,u,A,t)
    mul!(du,A,u)
end

prob = ODEProblem(f,u0,(0.0,10.0),A)
sol = solve(prob,ImplicitEuler())

using Plots
plot(sol[1])
plot!(sol[end])
```

[image]

Now we make the BCs non-zero. Notice that we just have to add back the `u[0]/dx^2` that we previously dropped off, so we have:

```
## Dirichlet non-zero BCs
## Note that the operator is no longer linear
## To handle affine BCs, we add the dropped term

u0 = @. (x - 0.5).^2 + 1/12
n = length(x)
A = 1/(2π/511)^2 * Tridiagonal(ones(n-1),-2ones(n),ones(n-1))

function f(du,u,A,t)
    mul!(du,A,u)
    # Now do the affine part of the BCs
    du[1] += 1/(2π/511)^2 * u0[1]
    du[end] += 1/(2π/511)^2 * u0[end]
end

prob = ODEProblem(f,u0,(0.0,10.0),A)
sol = solve(prob,ImplicitEuler())

plot(sol[1])
plot!(sol[end])
```

[image]

Now let's swap out the linear solver. [The documentation](http://diffeq.sciml.ai/latest/features/linear_nonlinear.html#Linear-Solvers:-linsolve-Specification-1) suggests that you should use `LinSolveCG` here, which looks like:

```
sol = solve(prob,ImplicitEuler(linsolve=LinSolveCG()))
```

There are some advantages to this, since it has a norm handling that helps conditioning. Howerver, the documentation also states that you can build your own linear solver routine. This is done by giving a `Val{:init}` dispatch that returns the type to use as the linear solver, so we do:

```
## Create a linear solver for CG
using IterativeSolvers

function linsolve!(::Type{Val{:init}},f,u0;kwargs...)
  function _linsolve!(x,A,b,update_matrix=false;kwargs...)
    cg!(x,A,b)
  end
end

sol = solve(prob,ImplicitEuler(linsolve=linsolve!))

plot(sol[1])
plot!(sol[end])
```

And there we are, non-zero Dirichlet Heat Equation with a Krylov method (conjugate gradients) for the linear solver, making it a Newton-Krylov method.

Comment: Did something change in the linsolve API? When I try to swap out the linear solver I do get the following error `ERROR: LoadError: function _linsolve! does not accept keyword arguments
Stacktrace:
 [1] kwfunc(::Any) at .\boot.jl:321
 [2] macro expansion at C:\Users\thiem\.julia\packages\DiffEqBase\dzpa7\src\diffeqfastbc.jl:71 [inlined]`

Comment: Yes, there was a small change. `linsolve!` needs to accept keyword arguments now, and they are now documented. Note that this [usage with CG is now standardized in the latest release](http://juliadiffeq.org/2019/07/05/AutomaticSparsity.html).